# javascriptで動的カレンダーをHTMLに出力したいです。

Tags: javascript

今生年月日をセレクトボックスに作ってみました。
しかし、このソースコードは非常に大きな問題点があります。
最後の日を出力する時もうし二月なのに31日まで出力しております。
私は今年月まで入力したら日は自動的に年月に合わせて日を出力したいです。

```
var date = new Date(1960, 02);
```

`var dateCnt = date.getUTCDate();`

上のソースコードを利用し、解決挑戦したができませんでした。

```
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=#D8D8D8>生年月日
    <td>
        <select name="year">
            <option value="">
            <script>
               for( var i=new Date( ).getFullYear( )-50 ; i<new Date( ).getFullYear( )+2 ; i++){
                   document.write( "<option value="+i+">"+i );
               }
            </script>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;年&nbsp;
        <select name="month">
            <option value="">
            <script>
               for( var i=1 ; i<=12 ; i++){
                   if(i<10){ document.write( "<option value='0"+i+"'>0"+i ); }
                   else   { document.write( "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i ); }
               }
            </script>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;月&nbsp;
        <select name="day">
            <option value="">
            <script>
               for( var i=1 ; i<=31 ; i++){
                   if(i<10){ document.write( "<option value='0"+i+"'>0"+i ); }
                   else   { document.write( "<option value='"+i+"'>"+i ); }
               }
            </script>
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;日
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/81406

Comment: ありがとうございます。あと掲示板に登録する時有効に使います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

年と月を指定して、その月は何日があるかを算出したいですよね。

```
function getDaysInOneMonth(year, month){  
  month = parseInt(month, 10);  
  var d= new Date(year, month, 0);  
  return d.getDate();  
}
```

このメソッドを使ってみてください。